# How to create lightning notification?

Tags: lightning, notification

I am trying to figure out how to create notifications here for a user to see when something happens to my custom object. I currently have a trigger which sends an email to the user and that works fine, but I would like to show a notification in Salesforce that shows up in the top right hand side "Notifications" bell.

I did a lot of searching and there is very little documentation on that notification bell, what shows up there, or how to create a notification. Does anyone have any information?

Bell:[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you receive a notification for approval requests or if mentioned in a Chatter posts. You can most likely create a notification by using the process builder to post to Chatter with the user @mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the bell notification through the new Summer '19 Custom Notifications feature however. It's a pretty simple process builder.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-custom-notifications-in-summer-19.html

Upside of this is that you can also deliver these as push notifications to the user's mobile device/watch etc. (so long as they have the Salesforce1 app installed).

Answer (score 0):

You can see updated and new functionalities related to notifications in the new release here:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-developer-i-certification-maintenance-winter-21/learn-whats-new-in-apex-for-platform-developers

Also you can see Toast Events to show instant message when the user is currently on the page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation