# How to create Notifications in Salesforce Lightning using Apex

Tags: apex, tasks, notification, task-notifications

I want my `Task` to appear as a notification in the top right corner in Lightning.

[image]

This is my Apex code:

```
        Task t = new Task();
        t.ReminderDateTime = DateTime.now();
        t.Priority = 'High';
        t.ActivityDate = Date.today();
        t.IsReminderSet = true;
        t.Subject = 'File Uploaded';
        t.OwnerId = ownerId;
        t.WhatId = recordId;
        t.Status = 'Open';
        insert t;
```

The task appears in the activity timeline, but I do not get a notification.

When I set the same properties using Process Builder it works:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for [How to create lightning notification?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179995/how-to-create-lightning-notification)

Comment: I've seen that question. My question specifically relates to achieving it using Apex. I am able to set the same properties using [Process Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233400/how-to-create-notifications-in-salesforce-lightning-via-process-builder) and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will leave it to the rest of the community then!

Comment: Have you reviewed [Enable Task Notifications in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_task_notifications.htm&type=5)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've checked and everything was already set as per the article.

Comment: @Robs The same code is working fine for me. Please recheck all the points in the link above.